# how to use portable imagemagick in php Exec()

Tags: php, imagemagick, exec, portability

Please help me.. My host company do not agree to install imagemagick on server so I have downloaded portable imagemagick version which does not require installation. I would like to test this portable version through php exec() command line.. how to do?

```
<?php
$magickpath = "c:/ImageMagick";

$env_path = $magickpath."/convert";

exec("$env_path k:\galstand.jpg k:\galstand.png");
?>
```

the above method does not works.

Comment: Please do a bit of research into what you're trying to accomplish before posting here - Google around, do a few experiments and then ask your question about any problems you have.

Comment: already I have googling a while but did not find a solution. I hope I can able to get solution here.

Comment: Do you get an error message? Have you confirmed that it works via command line (even on your own machine initially)?

Comment: yes sir, right now I am testing in local machine.. It return nothing..I have checked the Imagemagick through command line mode directly. It works well. so I would like to know how to run the same command in php  exec console

Comment: Is your hosting company running Windows?

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding and on confusion.. that code was tested in my local machine

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [ImageMagick: Command-line Tools](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php?ImageMagick=q4cdt5honberqbpqahhas1uh01) documentation? You can also use their [PHP API](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php).

Comment: No sir, thanks for the reply.. I do not worry about the commands.. I need one sample code. how to integrate php and imagemagick without env variable. I meant without installing Imagemagick

Comment: Hello sir, is there any possible ways? or should I need force my host company to install Imagemagick.

Comment: Read up on the PHP API. I have a link in the answer.

Comment: I hope you have answer about using Imagick or magickwand API.. I know both of them and i have good knowledge about Imagick PHP API. so I do not worry about that.. all I want Is this possible to Imagemagick command through PHP exec console without installation, without API..